# MouseEnter and mouseleave does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use mouseenter and mouseleave to change the background of an icon, but it is really bugger. When I hover over the icon, the background changes, when I move my mouse out, the background should go back to normal, but sometimes it doesn't. Can anyone help?

My code:

```
catItem$.on('mouseenter', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target$ = $(e.currentTarget),
        newCategory =  target$.attr('data-dest'),
        newCategoryItem = this.categories[newCategory];
    if (newCategory.isClicked) {
        return;
    }
    target$.find('.cat-icon').addClass('is-selected');
    target$.find('.cat-icon').css('background-image', 'url(' + newCategoryItem.lightIconImageURL + ')');
}.bind(this));

catItem$.on('mouseleave', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target$ = $(e.currentTarget),
        newCategory =  target$.attr('data-dest'),
        newCategoryItem = this.categories[newCategory];

    if (!newCategoryItem.isClicked) {
        target$.find('.cat-icon').removeClass('is-selected');
        target$.find('.cat-icon').css('background-image', 'url(' + newCategoryItem.darkIconImageURL + ')');
    }
}.bind(this));
```

I can't use CSS because the background image is dynamic on hover.

Comment: so from an accessibility standpoint, how would someone who's unable to use a mouse view the images?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the background to change on hover, have you thought about doing this with CSS rather than with JavaScript?

```
#item {
  background-image: url(someImage);
}
#item:hover {
  background-image: url(someOtherImage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code without the conditions to maybe understand what's going wrong:

```
catItem$.on('mouseenter', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target$ = $(e.currentTarget),
        newCategory =  target$.attr('data-dest'),
        newCategoryItem = this.categories[newCategory];
    target$.find('.cat-icon').addClass('is-selected');
    target$.find('.cat-icon').css('background-image', 'url(' + newCategoryItem.lightIconImageURL + ')');
}.bind(this));

catItem$.on('mouseleave', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target$ = $(e.currentTarget),
        newCategory =  target$.attr('data-dest'),
        newCategoryItem = this.categories[newCategory];
    target$.find('.cat-icon').removeClass('is-selected');
    target$.find('.cat-icon').css('background-image', 'url(' + newCategoryItem.darkIconImageURL + ')');
}.bind(this));
```

> Edit: assuming that sometimes your code works and sudden stops
>
> > EDIT2: Maybe, can be browser's cache, try:
> >
> > ```
> > var d = new Date();
> > var n = d.getTime();
> > target$.find('.cat-icon').css('background-image', 'url(' + newCategoryItem.lightIconImageURL + '?=' + d + ')');
> > ```

Answer (score -1):

Please see this example

```js
var i = 0;
$(".overout")
  .mouseover(function() {
    i += 1;
    $(this).find("span").text("mouse over x " + i);
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find("span").text("mouse out ");
  });

var n = 0;
$(".enterleave")
  .mouseenter(function() {
    n += 1;
    $(this).find("span").text("mouse enter x " + n);
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find("span").text("mouse leave");
  });
```

```css
.out {
  width: 40%;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  background-color: #d6edfc;
  float: left;
}

.in {
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  background-color: #fc0;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

p {
  line-height: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div class="out overout">
    <span>move your mouse</span>
    <div class="in">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="out enterleave">
    <span>move your mouse</span>
    <div class="in">
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: where;s the example?

Comment: Link only answers are not answers. Please either elaborate or change this to be a comment.